# Is there a way in R to combine columns based on a names column (0s involved)

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine a few columns. Consider these.

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 21 |
| Jake | 15 |
| Bill | 24 |
| Sophie | 30 |

| Name | Children |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 2 |
| Bill | 1 |

| Name | Pets |
| --- | --- |
| Jake | 1 |

The desired output is:

| Name | Age | Children | Pets | 50 more columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 21 | 2 | 0 | ... |
| Jake | 15 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| Bill | 24 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| Sophie | 30 | 0 | 0 | ... |

Note that I've got about 50 columns of different characteristics to combine, hence merge and cbind have caused me tremendous issues.

Comment: `merge(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), df3, all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: Is there a way to do one function that encompasses all? I have about 50 columns but don't want to call merge 50 times.

Comment: You mean you have 50 dataframes?. Not columns. each dataframe has the Name column and an extra column

Comment: Do you have a list of all the dataframes? Can you put them in a list?

Comment: Sorry yes, 50 dataframes. All contain the Name column but have different characteristics attached, i.e. Age, pets, mother's name, father's name, date of birth, country origin, no. cats, no. degrees, job switches, etc.

Comment: Yes I can, I believe I just call list(df1,df2,df3), etc. But in R, it simply prints the dataframes separately, whereas I want it all listed as one

Comment: Now put all the dataframes in a list the n do `Reduce(function(...)merge(..., all.x = TRUE), your_df_list)` where `your_df_list <-list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5,...)`

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented this, although Pets comes before Age, but I'd like Age to be the first column next to name. Is there anyway to keep that change?

Comment: you could rearrange, or ensure the df that has Age is before the one that has Names. The column arrangement can be fixed at the end. ie `my_final_df[, c(1, 3, 2, 4:50)]`

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll figure it out from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df4<-merge(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), df3, all.x = TRUE)
df4[is.na(df4)] <-0
df4
    Name Age Children Pets
1    Amy  21        2    0
2   Bill  24        1    0
3   Jake  15        0    1
4 Sophie  30        0    0
```

Note that if you have many dfs, you could do:

```
my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, ...)
Reduce(function(...)merge(..., all.x = TRUE), my_list)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do one function that encompasses all? I have about 50 columns but don't want to call merge 50 times.